# Delete class pointer does not free memory

Tags: c++, class, pointers, delete-operator

I have a class `testc` in file `main.cpp`. I control memory usage using `htop`. Compiler is g++. Operating system is Debian. I do not use any specific compile options:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main



    #include <vector>
    #include <set>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    using namespace std;

    class testc
    {
    public:
      vector <int> i;
      string str;
      //set <int> si;
      testc(){};
      ~testc() {};
    };

    int main() {
        testc* testc_ptr = new testc();
        cout<<"before filling"<<endl;
        getchar();
        for (int c=0; c< 1024*1024*10;c++) {
            testc_ptr->i.push_back(c);
            //testc_ptr->si.insert(c);
        }
        testc_ptr->str="some string";
        cout<<"after filling"<<endl;
        getchar();
        delete(testc_ptr);
        cout<<"after deletion"<<endl;
        getchar();
        return 1;
    };
```

It works perfectly. It free all memory allocated to class. But when I uncomment commented lines correspond to set, I have the problem. 
Before filling `htop` shows VIRT: 2988, RES: 908.
After filling `htop` shows VIRT: 306M, RES: 280M.
After deletion `htop` shows VIRT: 242M, RES: 240M.

Why memory allocated for set `si` has not been deleted, but for vector was? How it shall be deleted correctly?

Comment: Just because you delete memory in your program doesn't mean the underlying allocator is going to give that memory back to the OS immediately  Since in the end, after however many reallocations, the vector is a single block of memory it may be more likely to be given up where the set is a bunch of small nodes and combined with the vector reallocating while you fill it your memory map might look like swiss cheese.  Worry about not leaking memory, not how the allocator works unless it is an issue.

Comment: thank you. I include a code above in cycle and htop shows that it is everything ok.